# Error after adding AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios4, afnetworking

Created a brand new project added the `AFNetworking` library, and then added `SystemConfiguration` and `MobileCoreServices` linked libraries. Finally when i build the project i get an error in `AFHTTPClient.m` line number `152`;

```
for (id nestedKey in [dictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]]) {
```

The error says `Unexpected '@' in program`

Answer (score 0):

If to aren't using a recent version of Xcode it won't recognise the array literal syntax.

To see what goes with what - have a look at the [Objective-C Features Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/)

Comment: Could be compiler- or SDK-/deployment-settings, too. Be sure to use LLVM and at least iOS 5 as your target platform and base-SDK.

Comment: This feature is not tied to the version of iOS. Using subscript notation requires iOS5, but array literals deploy back for all versions as described in the document I added to my answer.

Comment: @Abizern To add to your answer, I'd like to note that backwards subscripting is available for `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`, but `NSOrderedSet` subscripting only works in iOS 6.